# Powershell module nesting

Tags: powershell, nested

I would like to have multiple modules/scripts nested, I would like to keep the actual files across multiple directories:

```
BuildTests[dir]  
|BuildTests.psd1  
|GenericTests[dir]  
||GenericTests.psd1  
||GenericTest1.ps1  
||GenericTest2.ps1  
|SpecificTests[dir]  
||SpecificTests.psd1  
||SpecificTest1.ps1  
||SpecificTest2.ps1
```

I want to keep 1 function per .ps1 file.
I have tried the following:

in BuildTests.psd1 define `NestedModules = @('.\GenericTests\GenericTests.psd1','.\SpecificTests\SpecificTests.psd1')`

in GenericTests.psd1 define `ScriptsToProcess = @('GenericTest1.ps1','GenericTest2.ps1')`
accordingly configure SpecificTests.psd1

Basically this works, however when checking get-module, I see all the functions from .ps1 files imported twice, checking further import-module with -verbose parameter, I can see that one time it is "loading module ...test1.ps1" and next line is "Dot-Sourcing the script file ....test1.ps1".

I have tried different variations in .psd1 (changing from .ps1 to .psm1 and including them in nestedmodules), but I always seem to end up with duplicates imported or no functions imported at all.

Comment: Any reason for "1 function per .ps1 file" ?

Comment: just for convenience, those could also be .psm1 files

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's working just fine, what got me confused was the verbose output listing exporting/importing same function multiple times:

```
PS D:\DevRepository\ParentModule> Import-Module .\ParentModule.psd1 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'D:\DevRepository\ParentModule\ParentModule.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'D:\DevRepository\ParentModule\Modules1\Modules1.psd1'.
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'D:\DevRepository\ParentModule\Modules1\TestCase1.ps1'.
VERBOSE: Dot-sourcing the script file 'D:\DevRepository\ParentModule\Modules1\TestCase1.ps1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'test-case1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'test-case1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'test-case1'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'test-case1'.
```

And then checking the module ExportedFunctions property:

```
PS D:\DevRepository\ParentModule> Get-Module ParentModule | select ExportedFunctions

ExportedFunctions
-----------------
{[test-case1, test-case1]}
```

Which actually lists key/value pairs:

```
PS D:\DevRepository\ParentModule> (Get-Module ParentModule).ExportedFunctions

Key        Value
---        -----
test-case1 test-case1
```